# How do I fix this post request in Angular

Tags: angular, post

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {ConfirmDialogComponent, ConfirmDialogModel} from '../confirm-dialog/confirm dialog.component';
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-chemical',
  templateUrl: './edit-chemical.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-chemical.component.css']
})
export class EditChemicalComponent implements OnInit {
  chemical_name: FormGroup;
  common_name: FormGroup;
  signal_word: FormGroup;
  chemical_solid_quantity: FormGroup;
  chemical_liquid_quantity: FormGroup;
  whmis_class: FormGroup;
  primary_hazard_class: FormGroup;
  secondary_hazard_class: FormGroup;
  category: FormGroup;
  staff_member_id: FormGroup;
  room_id: FormGroup;
  sds_id: FormGroup;

  id: string;
  private http: HttpClient;
  chemical: any;
  isLinear = true;

  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

  result: string;



  constructor(private httpValue: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public dialog: MatDialog, private router: Router) {
    this.http = httpValue;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.getChemical();
    

    this.firstFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      chemical_name: [this.chemical.chemical_name, Validators.required], //PROBLEM HERE
      common_name: [''],
      chemical_solid_quantity: ['0.00', Validators.required],
      chemical_liquid_quantity: ['0.00', Validators.required],
      whmis_class: ['', Validators.required],
      primary_hazard_class: ['', Validators.required],
      secondary_hazard_class: [''],
      category: ['', Validators.required],
      signal_word: ['', Validators.required],
      staff_member_id: ['', Validators.required],
      room_id: ['', Validators.required],
      sds_id: ['', Validators.required],


    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      chemical_solid_quantity: ['', Validators.required],
      chemical_liquid_quantity: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
  getChemical(): void {
    this.http.post(BASE_URL + 'SingleChemical',
      {
        chemical_id:   this.id,
      })
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.chemical = data;
          this.chemical = this.chemical.chemical[0];
          console.log(this.chemical.chemical_name); //this works fine
        },
        error => {
          // this._errorMessage = 'Connection Issue';
        });
  }


}
```

The this.chemical.chemical_name works fine in console so I do receive the response but it is not defined when setting it in this.firstFormGroup

Is there a way I can return or halt the next funtion until getChemicals() is completed. I removed parts of the code that had no relevance to the issue. The goal is to prefill the form with existing data to make it easier to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default form control value ​​for specific control in FormGroup this way in your code.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getChemical();
   this.firstFormGroup.controls.chemical_name.setValue(this.chemical.chemical_name);
}
```